# Is the phrase " as not + adverb or adjevtive as" used commonly?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is the phrase " as not + adverb or adjective as" used commonly?

For example, "A is as not many as B" and does this mean same as " A is as few as B"?

Comment: I don't think either "A is as not many as B" or "A is as few as B" are valid constructions. Can you give any more meaningful examples?

Comment: "The library has the books of A which is as not many as the books of B." and "The library has the books of A which is as few as the books of B".

Comment: @YuuichiTam - I think the problem is that the sentence would have to be "...the books of A, which ARE not as many..."  There are multiple books, so  "the books are" not "the books is".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not a common construction in English.

If it were used, I think many or most people would understand it with the sense you expect, but English does not express a positive relation with a negative-polarity word.  Instead, we have a variety of paired comparison words (few/many, more/less, etc.), and a number of common prefixes that can be tacked on to most words (*un-*, *anti-*, *dis-* and the like) to indicate negation.

So you would never find someone saying

> <sup>*</sup>We have as not many widgets as fooframs.
>   <sup>*</sup>Sense is as not common as sensibility.
>   <sup>*</sup>I am as not inclined toward this as Bob is.

Instead, they would say

> We have as few widgets as fooframs.
>   Sense is as uncommon as sensibility.
>   I am as disinclined toward this as Bob is.

(Note that certain words take particular prefixes; *disinclined* and *uncommon* are valid, but *uninclined* and *discommon* are not.)